# Unity + Rider - Running tests error: "The assembly for this test is not found"

Tags: unity-game-engine, rider

I get the error `The assembly for this test is not found` in Rider, when running Unity tests from Rider.

Answer (score 11):

By default, Rider run them as Edit mode tests. I found no options in the run configuration, but on the test panel, you have a select where you can choose `Unity - Play Mode`.

[image]